# PKIX path building failed when using spring with Kafka and schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, avro

I recently migrated an application from `Spring Boot 2.6.x` to `Spring Boot 3.0.2`, this app interacts with `Kafka` and a schema registry with self-signed certificates, which are imported in both the truststore as well as the keystore.
From what I can pinpoint the issue is related to the `AvroSerializer` (now version 7 before version 5) as it seems it does not take the SSL configuration from the properties file

```
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:41,947] [INFO] [i.c.k.s.KafkaAvroSerializerConfig AbstractConfig.java:376] KafkaAvroSerializerConfig values:
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  auto.register.schemas = true
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  avro.reflection.allow.null = false
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  avro.remove.java.properties = false
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  avro.use.logical.type.converters = false
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  basic.auth.credentials.source = URL
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.cache.expiry.buffer.seconds = 300
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.client.id = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.client.secret = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.credentials.source = STATIC_TOKEN
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.identity.pool.id = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.issuer.endpoint.url = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.logical.cluster = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.scope = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.scope.claim.name = scope
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.sub.claim.name = sub
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  bearer.auth.token = [hidden]
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  context.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.context.NullContextNameStrategy
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  id.compatibility.strict = true
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  latest.compatibility.strict = true
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  normalize.schemas = false
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  proxy.host =
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  proxy.port = -1
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.format = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.reflection = false
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.cipher.suites = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.engine.factory.class = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.key.password = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.keystore.key = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.keystore.location = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.keystore.password = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.keystore.type = JKS
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.provider = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.truststore.certificates = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.truststore.password = null
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.ssl.truststore.type = JKS
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  schema.registry.url = [https://xxx.xxx.xxxx]
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  use.latest.version = false
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  use.schema.id = -1
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

Which causes the following error when the app starts :

```
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,221] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.s.s.DefaultSslEngineFactory DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:264] Created SSL context with keystore SecurityStore(
path=/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks, modificationTime=Thu Feb 09 14:31:26 UTC 2023), truststore SecurityStore(path=/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks, modificationTime=Thu Feb 09 14:31:26 UTC 2023), provider SunJSSE.
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,242] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.p.i.Sender Sender.java:238] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Starting Kafka producer
 I/O thread.
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,243] [INFO] [o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser AppInfoParser.java:119] Kafka version: 3.3.2
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,243] [INFO] [o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser AppInfoParser.java:120] Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,243] [INFO] [o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser AppInfoParser.java:121] Kafka startTimeMs: 1675953102242
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,243] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.p.i.TransactionManager TransactionManager.java:988] [Producer clientId=kafka-client]
 Transition from state UNINITIALIZED to INITIALIZING
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,245] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer KafkaProducer.java:466] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Kafka produ
cer started
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,400] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.p.i.TransactionManager TransactionManager.java:1028] [Producer clientId=kafka-client
] Enqueuing transactional request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,401] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:1162] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Initialize c
onnection to node xxx.xxx.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,402] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.ClientUtils ClientUtils.java:113] Resolved host xxxxxx as xx.xx.xx.xx,xx.xx.xx.xx

swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,402] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:991] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Initiating co
nnection to node xxx.xxx.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) using address xxxxxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,420] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.n.Selector Selector.java:531] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Created socket with S
O_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,435] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:953] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Completed con
nection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,464] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.n.SslTransportLayer SslTransportLayer.java:882] [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.
SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=xxx.xxx.net/10.222.10.218:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@701bf320, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSL Handshake failed
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path
 to requested target
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.xxx.xxx.netssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:435)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:523)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:373)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:293)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:73)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:534)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:455)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.1.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid c
ertification path to requested target
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  ... 23 common frames omitted
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    |  ... 28 common frames omitted
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,466] [INFO] [o.a.k.c.n.Selector Selector.java:616] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Failed authentication
with xxx.xxx.net/10.222.10.218 (channelId=-1) (SSL handshake failed)
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,467] [INFO] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:937] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Node -1 discon
nected.
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,468] [ERROR] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:764] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Connection
to node -1 (xxx.xxx.net/10.222.10.218:9093) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,468] [WARN] [o.a.k.c.NetworkClient NetworkClient.java:1065] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Bootstrap bro
ker xxx.xxx.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | [2023-02-09 14:31:42,469] [DEBUG] [o.a.k.c.p.KafkaProducer KafkaProducer.java:1063] [Producer clientId=kafka-client] Exception
occurred during message send:
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
swarm-app.so5byi81c6md@swarmt33    | Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certifi
cation path to requested target
```

Below is my `application.properties` file

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9093
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer

spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.ssl.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-type=JKS

spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.producer.security.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-type=JKS

spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.key-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
spring.kafka.consumer.security.protocol=SSL

spring.kafka.schema.registry.ssl.key-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.schema.registry.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/var/lib/app/config/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.schema.registry.ssl.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.schema.registry.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
spring.kafka.schema.registry.security.protocol=SSL


spring.kafka.producer.client-id=clientId
spring.kafka.consumer.client-id=clientId
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=groupId


#
# Credentials
#

# Kafka
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.producer.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.consumer.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.schema.registry.ssl.trust-store-password=changeit
spring.kafka.schema.registry.ssl.key-store-password=changeit
```

Any ideas as to how to make the `Serializer` pickup the SSL config?

Current Stack:

- Spring boot 3.0.2
- Kafka Avro Serializer 7.3.1
- Spring Kafka 3.0.2
- Spring 6.0.4

Comment: Could you check with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491078/15228699

Comment: I see I will try this but can't I just added to the custom truststore  since this is specific only to the Kafka part of the code instead of modifying the truststore for the entire JVM?

Comment: I tried doing this and same error, I added this to my docker file
`RUN \
    cd $JAVA_HOME/lib/security \
    && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias sdb_root_ca -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/root_ca.crt`

Comment: Add the intermediate or sub ca certs too.

Comment: Yup thought of that too
`RUN \
    cd $JAVA_HOME/lib/security \
    && ls \
    && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias root_ca -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/root_ca.crt \
    && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias intermediate_ca_infra -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/intermediate_ca_infra.pem \
    && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias schema-registry -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/schema-registry.pem`
But still same error

Comment: Also If I use curl with cacert option it works so I'm really under the impression the Kafka producer is not picking up properly the certificate